# Disable Copy on UILabel with UserInteractionEnabled enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, tttattritubedlabel

I use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/kronik/TTTAttributedLabel) for customizing my UILabel. But there is a problem, i do not want to have the function "copy to clipboard" when i hold my finger on the label and, in the official documentation, seems that there is no way to disable this function.

Anyone know how to do this?

PS: sorry for my first post, it was night in Italy and i was very very tired. Sorry for my bad english.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by copy? say more...

Comment: You can not copy from UILabel, It should me TextField or Textview.

Comment: Sorry, i've updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitHub fork you linked is not the [original project by Mattt](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel).

If you'd like to continue using the fork, you can subclass it and override `canPerformAction:withSender:` to return `NO`:

```
- (BOOL) canPerformAction:(SEL) action withSender:(id)sender {
    return NO;
}
```